# How to play audio file using OS

Tags: python, audio, operating-system

I am a beginner in doing this, and I saw that I need to import OS to play and audio file using python. Yet when I run my code of Jupyter Notebook, I get an error: "sh: AudioFiles/Hello.wav: Permission Denied. How do I fix this?

I am a beginner so I don't know if this is correct, if not, it would be helpful for a correction in code

Here is my code:

```
import os 
file = "AudioFiles/Hello.wav"
os.system(file)
```